# How to pull the column indices when matching the rows of a dataframe and a vector

Tags: r, dataframe, vector, indexing

Say I have a dataframe of letters like so:

```
  X1 X2 X3
1  G  A  C
2  G  T  C
3  G  T  C
4  A  T  G
5  A  C  G
```

And a vector like so:
`ref <- c("A", "C", "C", "A", "G")`

Going row-wise, how do I pull the column indices of the dataframe which match the vector?

So the answer should be a vector of numbers like so:
`2, 3, 3, 1, 3`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use

```
max.col(df1 == ref)
#[1] 2 3 3 1 3
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(X1 = c("G", "G", "G", "A", "A"), X2 = c("A", "T", 
"T", "T", "C"), X3 = c("C", "C", "C", "G", "G")), class = "data.frame",
row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5"))
```